# error C7537: OpenGL does not allow '?' after a type specifier, but there isn't

Tags: opengl, glsl, nvidia

My shader doesn't include any `?` at all. I've searched for unicode and unprintable characters and found none. What does this error mean?

```
error C7537: OpenGL does not allow '?' after a type specifier
error C7589: OpenGL does not allow a parameter to be a buffer
error C1012: abstract parameters not allowed in function definition "myfunc"
```

This is the function it points to (I've cut it down a fair bit from its original form).

```
void myfunction(int buffer)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`buffer` is a reserved word in GLSL for declaring [SSBO interface blocks](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)), although the error is a little misleading compared to the following:

```
void myfunction(int uniform)
{
}
```

Which gives:

```
error C7537: OpenGL does not allow 'uniform' after a type specifier
```

Comment: Also, if you're not using GLSL 4.30, the compiler shouldn't complain about that. So if you use an earlier version and it still complains, that sounds like a driver bug.